# Serp Tracker PHP script

Tags: php, class, function, seo, keyword

I've been trying to code my own keyword position ranking scanner for SEO purposes. I found a PHP class that looks like it will be very helpful but I can't figure out how to get it working.

I'm fairly new to using classes/functions with PHP.

This is the code I found:
http://www.andreyvoev.com/programming/simple-serp-tracker-php-class/

I've copied and pasted it exactly and it's still not working.  Would someone be willing to explain it to me?

**EDIT**

What I ended up doing was put the whole thing in one script, I have the class at the beginning of the script along with the class GoogleTracker and then I have the bit that runs it.

```
$test =  new GoogleTracker(array ('lsp'), 'adventuretime.wikia.com', 50);
        //$test->use_proxy('proxy.txt');
        $test->run();

        $results = $test->get_results();
       // $debug = $test->get_debug_info();

        print $results;
        //print_r($debug);
```

And when I run it in my browser the only that that prints is

```
Array()
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it the script?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem, how are you running this script?  Are you testing it on your local machine?  Do you have php installed?

Comment: I actually running it on my server and PHP is installed.  When you run it, are you getting the intended results?

Comment: Assuming the results are a non-empty `print_r`'d array, like so: `Array ( [lsp] => 3 ) ================
Array ( [time] => Array ( [lsp] => 0.930 ) )`, yes.  What is your file name?

Comment: What php version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it took me so long to see this.. yes, you are doing something wrong.  You are attempting to convert an array to a string.

This does not work with a normal [`print()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) function, as it expects a string as input.. not a mixed variable.  To view the results, you either want [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), or to look at the array key directly:

```
$results = $test->get_results();
print($results["lsp"]);
```

Comment: Given you are not on a development server, but a live one, depending on your error catching setup, it may or may not be printing all errors/notices to a file in the same directory labeled 'error_log'.  If is there, this error log would likely have the notice `Notice: Array to string conversion in path/to/file/scan.php on line 10`, telling you what happened.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I apologize for not replying sooner, I've been pretty busy at work. I'm going to see if I can find an error log, as well.

Answer (score 0):

you must include such class into your code :

```
include('serp_tracker.php');
// include the class GoogleTracker extends , the second class of bottom 

$test =  new GoogleTracker(array('git'), 'www.kernel.org', 50);
//$test->use_proxy('proxy.txt');
$test->run();

print_r($test->get_results());
echo "================<br>";
print_r($test->get_debug_info());
```

Comment: Yeah, I did know that and did it but when I run the script the only thing that prints is "Array()"  that's it. :/

Comment: @Elizabeth_Geniveve Show us exactly what you did.